# How to make transparent background of a gif animation?

Tags: image-editing, animated-gif

I have a gif animation with white background.
Is there a simple way (e.g., free or shareware application) to remove this white background and make it transparent?

Comment: Try [this site](http://www.online-image-editor.com/help/transparency) (the Transparency option can be found under "Wizards").

Comment: Related http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39772/making-backgrounds-of-animated-gif-files-transparent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use an online editing service like [gifmagic.com](http://www.gifmagic.com)

Comment: Thanks Duke, I tried, but it seems - it's not possible. After clicking `Edit-Transparency-Add` and click on the white background - the entire gif disappears. I saved and downloaded and got a still image (not animated).

Comment: Well that's weird. Try doing it in a different browser or try a different site - search google for "online gif edit". There's many of them out there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Online Image Editor](http://www.online-image-editor.com/) tool.

You can find this option in:

```
Wizards --> Transparency.
```

Working fine!

Comment: FYI many proxies block this tool as a potential security threat.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to create a Photoshop script <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> would be:

1. Select all
2. Select color
3. Remove this color
4. Unselect all
5. Activate next frame
6. Choose next video step

Then run this script from the first frame of opened animated GIF-file. For 100 frames 100 click of mouse = 30 sec.

File-> Save for WEB.